# Remove # from href calling JS function?

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a function which is called from a html link like this:

```
 <a href='#' onclick='javascript:populate("m")'>My Messages</a><br/>
```

Function called:

```
 function populate(q){

    switch(q){
    case 'm':  messages_document(call_data(q+'.php','main')); break;
    }
    return (false);
  }
```

The problem i have is the url in the browser adds a # to the it - which seems to prevent me clicking the link again unless i remove the hash, is there a way to stop it loading in the browser url ?

Comment: Just as a side comment, you don't need 'javascript: function' in the 'onclick' event; you can just do 'onclick="function();"'

Comment: It works here. http://jsfiddle.net/kZtnm/

Comment: What I am saying is that you can click it multiple times.

Comment: @TylerCrompton not with a function http://jsfiddle.net/kZtnm/3/

Comment: @Daedalus what do you mean lol ?

Comment: @Dave I mean exactly what I say; your script [isn't loaded in the document head](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/kZtnm/7/); if it is, it works fine.

Comment: Doesn't even work once for me. My console was saying that `test` was undefined. Fixed and works. http://jsfiddle.net/kZtnm/4/

Comment: @TylerCrompton I forgot to update the fiddle; it works now.

Comment: And just a suggestion, show some love for your JavaScript-disabling brethren by replacing the `#` with a valid URL in which one can read their messages because the link will work as a link if JavaScript is disabled. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onclick='return populate("m");'
```

Comment: @Dave note that it only works as long as the `populate` function returns `false` (Which it does)

Comment: My personal preference would be to take out `return (false);` from `populate` and replace `onclick`'s value with `populate("m"); return false;`. The reasoning behind this is because the function shouldn't return `false` if it works, IMHO.

Comment: @Esailija i seem to have to remove href="#"

Comment: I hear that returning `false` only works in certain browsers, though I've never tested.

Answer (score 0):

Load your script in the document head(that is, stuff it between two `<head>` and `<script type="text/javascript">` tags).  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/kZtnm/8/):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(id){
            alert(id);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<a href='#' onclick="test('Test');">My Messages</a>​
```

I've tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="populate('m');">My Messages</a>
<script>
function populate(q) {
    switch(q) {
        case 'm':  messages_document(call_data(q + '.php', 'main')); break;
    }
  }
</script>
```